# Is there an elegant way to get a set of rows for the last x days in MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the following Select Statement to get a set of rows with data for the last x days which I will use to join with other business data to create charts and i was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it ( I need the last 28 days).

```
    SELECT *
FROM (
      VALUES (0,
              dateadd(DAY, 0, convert(date, getdate())),
              datepart(WEEKDAY, dateadd(DAY, 0, CONVERT(date, getdate()))),
              datepart(ISO_WEEK, dateadd(DAY, 0, CONVERT(date, getdate())))),
             (1,
             dateadd(DAY, -1, convert(date, getdate())),
             datepart(WEEKDAY, dateadd(DAY, -1, CONVERT(date, getdate()))),
             datepart(ISO_WEEK, dateadd(DAY, -1, CONVERT(date, getdate()))))
      ) V(DayValue, DateValue, DayPart, WeekPart)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using the following Select Statement to get a set of rows with data for the last

I recursive CTE is a pretty simple way to generate a handful of dates:

```
with dates as (
      select convert(date, getdate()) as dte, 1 as n
      union all
      select dateadd(day, -1, dte), n + 1
      from dates
      where n < 28
     )
select *
from dates;
```

For more than 100 days, you need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

Of course, if you have a calendar tables or numbers table, that can be used.  In fact, any table with at least 28 rows can be use:

```
with dates as (
      select top (28) dateadd(day, 
                     1 - row_number() over (order by (select null)),
                     convert(date, getdate())
                    ) as dte
      from t      
     )
select *
from dates;
```